# Как сгрупировать дубликаты первого элемента во вложенных списках с просуммировав вторые элементы?

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
[['var1' 'val1'], ['var2' 'val2'], ['var1' 'val4'], ['var3' 'val1'], ['var4' 'val1'], ['var4' 'val15']]
```

Необходимо создать список с уникальными `var` и просуммировав значения `val`

```
dump = []
f = open('D:\\python\dm.txt')
f.read(1)
i = 0
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    line = line.split(' - ', 2)

    print(line[0]+' = '+line[1]+ ' шт')
    for dat in dump:
       if print(dat[0] == line[0]):
            print(line[0])
        #else:
        #dump.append([line[0], line[1]])

    i += 1 
dump.sort()
print(dump)
```

Должно получится:

```
 [['var1' 'val1+val4'], ['var2' 'val2'], ['var3' 'val1'], ['var4' 'val1+val15']]
```

Comment: [['var1' 'val1+val4'], ['var2' 'val2'], ['var3' 'val1'], ['var4' 'val1+val15']] Т.е. Ключ=Значение . Где ключ должен быть уникальным, а значение приплюсовать к существующему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже у автора вопроса числовые данные на месте второго элемента вложенных списков:

```
In [7]: data = \
   ...: [['var1', 11],
   ...:  ['var2', 12],
   ...:  ['var1', 13],
   ...:  ['var3', 14],
   ...:  ['var4', 15],
   ...:  ['var4', 16]]
```

решение в данном случае будет выглядеть так:

```
In [8]: res = [[a, sum(el[1] for el in b)]
   ...:        for a,b in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0]),
   ...:                           key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

результат:

```
In [9]: res
Out[9]: [['var1', 24], ['var2', 12], ['var3', 14], ['var4', 31]]
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо! Помогло! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

исходные данные:

```
data = \
[['var1', 'val1'],
 ['var2', 'val2'],
 ['var1', 'val4'],
 ['var3', 'val1'],
 ['var4', 'val1'],
 ['var4', 'val15']]
```

для решения воспользуйтесь [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [[a, "+".join(el[1] for el in b)] 
       for a,b in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0]), 
                          key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

---

результат:

```
In [26]: res
Out[26]:
[['var1', 'val1+val4'],
 ['var2', 'val2'],
 ['var3', 'val1'],
 ['var4', 'val1+val15']]
```

Comment: Отлично! Единственное, в значениях - цифры. Их надо суммировать. Я не точно выразился.

Comment: @hitlowww, в следующий раз, когда будете задавать новые вопросы, приводите примеры данных максимально приближенные к настоящим данным ;)

Comment: обязательно. Спасибо. Я только обучаюсь. Я пытаюсь суммировать, но у меня получаются только синтаксические ошибки(

Comment: @hitlowww, советую вам открыть новый SO вопрос и привести в нем пример соответствующих входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Мой овет отвечает на вопрос со строковыми данными (такими, которые вы привели в качестве примера) и он может быть полезен не только вам, но и всем тем кто попадет сюда из поисковиков, поэтому я изменять его не буду

Comment: @hitlowww, если я правильно понял структуру ваших данных, то просто замените `"+".join(` --> `sum(`

Answer (score 0):

Напрашивается использование словаря

```py
# create dictionary
result = {}

for line in f:
  # parse line...
  # skiped
  key, val = line
  
  if key in result:
    result[key] = result[key] + val
  else:
    result[key] = val

print(result)
```

Comment: print(result) выдает только крайнее значение.